# libgeos installation fall on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

i was able to install libgeos c++ on ubuntu 20.04 manually with the following command

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geos/libgeos++-dev_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geos/libgeos-dev_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geos/libgeos-c1v5_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geos/libgeos-3.9.0_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

```
  sudo apt install ./libgeos-3.9.0_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb
  
  sudo apt install ./libgeos-c1v5_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

  sudo apt install ./libgeos-dev_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb

  sudo apt install ./libgeos++-dev_3.9.0-1_amd64.deb
```

but it looks geos deleted the 3.9.0 related files/ packages, I tried to change those files to 3.11 it not working out and says a broken package. I also try the installation guide here https://libgeos.org/usage/install/#ubuntu, but don't get any luck
so anyone recently install geos successfully?

Comment: Why do you perform these unsafe actions? `sudo apt install libgeos++-dev` should install maintained by Ubuntu team libgeos.

Comment: thank! it was give me some error like broken package before but I will try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @273K, in the comments:

```
sudo apt install libgeos++-dev
```

This works for me after I remove all the libgeos files I get before I `rm` everything and use the command.